# Expected member name, ';' at end of list, and require a specifier?

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

```
@implementation GameScene {

 -(id)init {
self = [super init]
if (self != nil) {

    BackgroundLayer *backgroundLayer = [BackgroundLayer node];
    [self addChild:backgroundLayer z:0];

    GameplayLayer *gameplayLayer = [GameplayLayer node];
    [self addChild:gameplayLayer z:5];
}
return self;
 }

 @end
```

Ive done it like this before, But ever since I updated xCode I have been recieving the following error messaged all pinned to the -(id) line.

Type name requires a specifier or qualifier

Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers

and

Expected ';' at end of declaration list

Im not sure what to do from here, cant seem to fix these!

Comment: I am missing a } in the above post, but this is not the problem, Ive added it since and still the same results!

Comment: You are missing a `;` on the `self = [super init]` line.

Comment: Didn't see that, its fixed now, but the same 3 error messages are still present!

Comment: Then the error is outside the code that you have pasted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't have an opening brace after `@implementation` unless you define extra variables in a block, like this:

```
@implementation GameScene {
    int _variable;
}
- (id)init {
    ...
}
...
@end
```

The class methods (init, etc) should not be enclosed in braces, so the fix to your compiler error is to simply remove the opening brace.

Comment: This was the problem, thank you very much! Soon as I can mark it as answered I will!

Answer (score 0):

You have an open { on your GameScene implementation line.

change your code to

```
@implementation GameScene

 -(id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {

    BackgroundLayer *backgroundLayer = [BackgroundLayer node];
    [self addChild:backgroundLayer z:0];

    GameplayLayer *gameplayLayer = [GameplayLayer node];
    [self addChild:gameplayLayer z:5];
}
return self;
}

 @end
```

Comment: Thank you for this as well, But I have to give  Tore Olsen the answer on this one, his explanation was not only first but also very helpful in explaining it and not just "change your code to this"!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple enough. I solved this issue by placing appropriate "{" and "}" braces in code.
Your code should be as

```
    @implementation GameScene 

     -(id)init {
        self = [super init]
        if (self != nil) {

        BackgroundLayer *backgroundLayer = [BackgroundLayer node];
        [self addChild:backgroundLayer z:0];

        GameplayLayer *gameplayLayer = [GameplayLayer node];
        [self addChild:gameplayLayer z:5];
      }
        return self;
     }

   @end
```